# Make YARD ignore certain class extensions

Tags: configuration, documentation, yard

I am getting several warnings when generating my project documentation because YARD cannot parse some external class extensions

```
[warn]: in YARD::Handlers::Ruby::MixinHandler: Undocumentable mixin: YARD::Parser::UndocumentableError for class MyClass
[warn]:     in file 'lib/Project/myclass.rb':7:

    7: include Virtus.model
```

The root of the problem is one class extension that cannot be parsed. I know I could just run **yard -q** to suppress all warnings, but I would rather supress individual extensions than everything.

As far as I can see in the help, I could **--exclude** but right now, the offending class is part of an external gem. I also tried **@!parse** without success

```ruby
class MyClass

  # @!parse Virtus.model
  include Virtus.model
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I was able to hide the warning by obfuscating the inclusion so YARD cannot detect it:

```ruby
class MyClass
  send :include, Virtus.model
end
```

There is more discussion of this issue on github:

https://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues/546